# ActivePivot leaf level aggregation and Analysis dimension

Tags: analysis, dimension, activepivot

lets say I have an ActivePivot cube with facts containing just Value, and Currency.
lets say my cube has Currency as a regular dimension.

We fill the cube with facts that have many currencies.

We have a forex service that takes the currency and reference currency to get a rate.

Now, Value.SUM doesn't make any sense, we are adding up values with different currencies, so we want to have a post processor that can convert all values to a reference currency, say, USD, then sum them, so we write a post processor that extends *ADynamicAggregationPostProcessor*, specify Currency as a leaf level dimension, and use the forex service to do the conversion, and we are happy.

But, lets say we don't want to convert just to USD, we want to convert to 10 different currencies and see the results next to each other on the screen.
So we create an Analysis dimension, say ReferenceCurrency, with 10 members.

My question is: how can I alter the above post processor to handle the Analysis dimension? The plain vanilla *ADynamicAggregationPostProcessor* does not handle Analysis dimensions, only the default member is visible to this post processor. Other post processors that handle Analysis dimensions, like *DefaultAggregatePostProcessor* do not have a means for specifying leaf levels, so I cannot get the aggregates by Currency, and so cannot do the forex conversion. How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use two advanced features of ActivePivot at the same time (Analysis dimensions to expose several outcomes of the same aggregate, and dynamic aggregation to aggregate amounts expressed in different currencies).

Separately each one is fairly easy to setup through configuration and a few lines of code to inject. But to interleave both you will need to understand the internals of post processor evaluation, and inject business logic at the right places.

Here is an example based on ActivePivot 4.3.3. It has been written in the open-source Sandbox Application so that you can run it quickly before adapting it to your own project.

First we need a simple analysis dimension to hold the possible reference currencies:

```
package com.quartetfs.pivot.sandbox.postprocessor.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.cube.hierarchy.axis.impl.AAnalysisDimension;
import com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetExtendedPluginValue;

/**
 * 
 * An analysis dimension bearing the
 * list of possible reference currencies.
 * 
 * @author Quartet FS
 *
 */
@QuartetExtendedPluginValue(interfaceName = "com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.cube.hierarchy.IDimension", key = ReferenceCurrencyDimension.TYPE)
public class ReferenceCurrencyDimension extends AAnalysisDimension {

    /** serialVersionUID */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42706811331081328L;

    /** Default reference currency */
    public static final String DEFAULT_CURRENCY = "EUR";

    /** Static list of non-default possible reference currencies */
    public static final List<Object[]> CURRENCIES;
    static {
        List<Object[]> currencies = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        currencies.add(new Object[] {"USD"});
        currencies.add(new Object[] {"GBP"});
        currencies.add(new Object[] {"JPY"});
        CURRENCIES = Collections.unmodifiableList(currencies);
    }

    /** Plugin type */
    public static final String TYPE = "REF_CCY";

    /** Constructor */
    public ReferenceCurrencyDimension(String name, int ordinal, Properties properties, Set<String> measureGroups) {
        super(name, ordinal, properties, measureGroups);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDefaultDiscriminator(int levelOrdinal) { return DEFAULT_CURRENCY; }

    @Override
    public Collection<Object[]> buildDiscriminatorPaths() { return CURRENCIES; }

    @Override
    public int getLevelsCount() { return 1; }

    @Override
    public String getLevelName(int levelOrdinal) {
        return levelOrdinal == 0 ? "Currency" : super.getLevelName(levelOrdinal);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() { return TYPE; }

}
```

Then the post processor itself, a customized dynamic aggregation post processor modified to handle the analysis dimension and output the same aggregate multiple times, one time per reference currency.

```
package com.quartetfs.pivot.sandbox.postprocessor.impl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.IActivePivot;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.ILocation;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.ILocationPattern;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.aggfun.IAggregationFunction;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.cellset.ICellSet;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.cube.hierarchy.IDimension;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.cube.hierarchy.axis.IAxisMember;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.impl.Location;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.postprocessing.impl.ADynamicAggregationPostProcessor;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.postprocessing.impl.ADynamicAggregationProcedure;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.query.IQueryCache;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.query.aggregates.IAggregatesRetriever;
import com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.query.aggregates.RetrievalException;
import com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetException;
import com.quartetfs.fwk.QuartetExtendedPluginValue;
import com.quartetfs.pivot.sandbox.service.impl.ForexService;
import com.quartetfs.tech.type.IDataType;
import com.quartetfs.tech.type.impl.DoubleDataType;

/**
 * Forex post processor with two features:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Dynamically aggregates amounts in their native currencies into reference currency
 * <li>Applies several reference currencies, exploded along an analysis dimension.
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @author Quartet FS
 */
@QuartetExtendedPluginValue(interfaceName = "com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.postprocessing.IPostProcessor", key = ForexPostProcessor.TYPE)
public class ForexPostProcessor extends ADynamicAggregationPostProcessor<Double> {

    /** serialVersionUID */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 15874126988574L;

    /** post processor plugin type */
    public final static String TYPE = "FOREX";

    /** Post processor return type */
    private static final IDataType<Double> DATA_TYPE = new DoubleDataType();

    /** Ordinal of the native currency dimension */
    protected int nativeCurrencyDimensionOrdinal;

    /** Ordinal of the native currency level */
    protected int nativeCurrencyLevelOrdinal;

    /** Ordinal of the reference currencies dimension */
    protected int referenceCurrenciesOrdinal;

    /** forex service*/
    private ForexService forexService;

    /** constructor */
    public ForexPostProcessor(String name, IActivePivot pivot) {
        super(name, pivot);
    }

    /** Don't forget to inject the Forex service into the post processor */
    public void setForexService(ForexService forexService) {
        this.forexService = forexService;
    }

    /** post processor initialization */
    @Override
    public  void init(Properties properties) throws QuartetException {
        super.init(properties);

        nativeCurrencyDimensionOrdinal = leafLevelsOrdinals.get(0)[0];
        nativeCurrencyLevelOrdinal = leafLevelsOrdinals.get(0)[1];

        IDimension referenceCurrenciesDimension = getDimension("ReferenceCurrencies");
        referenceCurrenciesOrdinal = referenceCurrenciesDimension.getOrdinal();
    }

    /** 
     * Handling of the analysis dimension:<br>
     * Before retrieving leaves, wildcard the reference currencies dimension.
     */
    protected ICellSet retrieveLeaves(ILocation location, IAggregatesRetriever retriever) throws RetrievalException {
        ILocation baseLocation = location;
        if(location.getLevelDepth(referenceCurrenciesOrdinal-1) > 0) {
            Object[][] array = location.arrayCopy();
            array[referenceCurrenciesOrdinal-1][0] = null;  // wildcard
            baseLocation = new Location(array);
        }
        return super.retrieveLeaves(baseLocation, retriever);
    }



    /**
     * Perform the evaluation of the post processor on a leaf (as defined in the properties).
     * Here the leaf level is the UnderlierCurrency level in the Underlyings dimension .
     */
    @Override
    protected Double doLeafEvaluation(ILocation leafLocation, Object[] underlyingMeasures) throws QuartetException {

        // Extract the native and reference currencies from the evaluated location
        String currency = (String) leafLocation.getCoordinate(nativeCurrencyDimensionOrdinal-1, nativeCurrencyLevelOrdinal);
        String refCurrency = (String) leafLocation.getCoordinate(referenceCurrenciesOrdinal-1, 0);

        // Retrieve the measure in the native currency
        double nativeAmount = (Double) underlyingMeasures[0];

        // If currency is reference currency or measureNative is equal to 0.0 no need to convert
        if ((currency.equals(refCurrency)) || (nativeAmount == .0) ) return nativeAmount;

        // Retrieve the rate and rely on the IQueryCache 
        // in order to retrieve the same rate for the same currency for our query
        IQueryCache queryCache = pivot.getContext().get(IQueryCache.class);
        Double rate = (Double) queryCache.get(currency + "_" + refCurrency);
        if(rate == null) {
            Double rateRetrieved = forexService.retrieveQuotation(currency, refCurrency);
            Double rateCached = (Double) queryCache.putIfAbsent(currency + "_" + refCurrency, rateRetrieved);
            rate = rateCached == null ? rateRetrieved : rateCached;
        }

        // Compute equivalent in reference currency
        return  rate == null ? nativeAmount :  nativeAmount * rate;
    }

    @Override
    protected IDataType<Double> getDataType() { return DATA_TYPE; }

    /** @return the type of this post processor, within the post processor extended plugin. */
    @Override
    public String getType() { return TYPE; }


    /**
     * @return our own custom dynamic aggregation procedure,
     * so that we can inject our business logic.
     */
    protected DynamicAggregationProcedure createProcedure(ICellSet cellSet, IAggregationFunction aggregationFunction, ILocationPattern pattern) {
        return new DynamicAggregationProcedure(cellSet, aggregationFunction, pattern);
    }

    /**
     * Custom dynamic aggregation procedure.<br>
     * When the procedure is executed over a leaf location,
     * we produce several aggregates instead of only one:
     * one aggregate for each of the visible reference currencies.
     */
    protected class DynamicAggregationProcedure extends ADynamicAggregationProcedure<Double> {

        protected DynamicAggregationProcedure(ICellSet cellSet, IAggregationFunction aggregationFunction, ILocationPattern pattern) {
            super(ForexPostProcessor.this, aggregationFunction, cellSet, pattern);
        }

        /**
         * Execute the procedure over one row of the leaf cell set.
         * We compute one aggregate for each of the reference currencies.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean execute(ILocation location, int rowId, Object[] measures) {
            if(location.getLevelDepth(referenceCurrenciesOrdinal-1) > 0) {

                // Lookup the visible reference currencies
                IDimension referenceCurrenciesDimension = pivot.getDimensions().get(referenceCurrenciesOrdinal);
                List<IAxisMember> referenceCurrencies = (List<IAxisMember>) referenceCurrenciesDimension.retrieveMembers(0);
                for(IAxisMember member : referenceCurrencies) {
                    Object[][] array = location.arrayCopy();
                    array[referenceCurrenciesOrdinal-1][0] = member.getDiscriminator();
                    ILocation loc = new Location(array);
                    super.execute(loc, rowId, measures);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.execute(location, rowId, measures);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Double doLeafEvaluation(ILocation location, Object[] measures) throws QuartetException {
            return ForexPostProcessor.this.doLeafEvaluation(location, measures);
        }

    }

}
```

In the description of your cube, the analysis dimension and the post processor would be exposed like this:

```
...
<dimension name="ReferenceCurrencies" pluginKey="REF_CCY" />
...
<measure name="cross" isIntrospectionMeasure="false">
    <postProcessor pluginKey="FOREX">
        <properties>
            <entry key="id" value="pv.SUM" />
            <entry key="underlyingMeasures" value="pv.SUM" />
            <entry key="leafLevels" value="UnderlierCurrency@Underlyings" />
        </properties>
    </postProcessor>
</measure>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Analysis Dimensions brings so much complexity they should be considered apart of the others features of your cube. One way to handle your issue is then:

1. Add a first measure expanding properly along the analysis dimension. In your case, it will simply copy the underlying measure along ReferenceCurrency, optionally doing the FX conversion. This measure may be used as underlying of several measures.
2. Add a second measure, based on usual dynamic aggregation. This second implementation is very simple as it does not know there is an analysis dimension.